# Rails 3.1 CoffeeScript/JQuery - How to change the source of an image in a div?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I would like to change the image of a link with jquery. This is what I tried :

In my Haml file :

```
.selected
  = link_to image_tag('/assets/unselected.png'), {:controller => Posts, :action => "update", :selected => true}, :id => "selected_post", :remote => true, :method => :put
```

After some stuff in my posts_controller, here is the update.js.coffee where I tried to change the image of the link with a new one called selected.png :

```
$("selected_post").attr 'src', '/assets/selected.png'
```

I does not work and if I call an alert with :

```
alert $("selected_post").attr 'src'
```

It sends "undefined".

I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#selected_post` should be your selector

`#` is the css shortcut for the `id` attribute. So this should work:

```
$("#selected_post").attr 'src', '/assets/selected.png'
```