# Ruby on Rails Like button with image instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am currently working with the Acts_As_Votable gem in Ruby to use a Like link on each of my posts so that users can vote. I found a great answer on here that helped be do exactly that but I'm trying to figure out how I can use a heart icon image instead of the Like/Dislike text. I want the image to update without refreshing, just like the text links do but can't figure out the logic. Here is the current code I am using:

**controllers/prides_controller.rb**

```
def like
     @pride = Pride.find(params[:id])
     @pride.liked_by current_user

     if request.xhr?
       render json: { count: @pride.get_likes.size, id: params[:id] }
     else
       redirect_to @pride
     end
end

def dislike
    @pride = Pride.find(params[:id])
    @pride.disliked_by current_user
    if request.xhr?
      render json: { count: @pride.get_likes.size, id: params[:id] }
    else
      redirect_to @pride
    end
end
```

**prides/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="single-heart-this">
  <% if current_user.liked? @pride %>

      <span class="heart-icon-loved">
        <%= link_to "Dislike", dislike_pride_path(@pride), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, data: { toggle_text: 'Like', toggle_href: like_pride_path(@pride), id: @pride.id } %></span>
  <% else %>
    <span class="heart-icon">
      <%= link_to "Like", like_pride_path(@pride), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, data: { toggle_text: 'Dislike', toggle_href: dislike_pride_path(@pride), id: @pride.id } %></span>
  <% end %>
  <span class="heart-no" data-id="<%= @pride.id %>"><%= @pride.get_likes.size %></span>
<% end %>    
</div>
```

**javascript/pride.js.erb**

```
# Rails creates this event, when the link_to(remote: true)
# successfully executes
$(document).on 'ajax:success', 'a.vote', (status,data,xhr)->
  # the `data` parameter is the decoded JSON object
  $(".heart-no[data-id=#{data.id}]").text data.count
  return
```

**javascript/prides.js.coffee**

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
$(document).on 'ajax:success', 'a.vote', (status,data,xhr)->
  # update counter
  $(".heart-no[data-id=#{data.id}]").text data.count

  # toggle links
  $("a.vote[data-id=#{data.id}]").each ->
    $a = $(this)
    href = $a.attr 'href'
    text = '$a.text()'
    $a.text($a.data('toggle-text')).attr 'href', $a.data('toggle-href')
    $a.data('toggle-text', 'text').data 'toggle-href', href
    return

  return
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

Add: class: "Change_me" to your link

```
    <%= link_to image_tag("Dislike.png"), dislike_pride_path(@pride), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, data: { toggle_href: like_pride_path(@pride), id: @pride.id }, class: "change_me" %>
```

src: [link_to image_tag with inner text or html in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387122/link-to-image-tag-with-text-in-rails)

In your coffeescript, change the image src

$(".change_me").attr 'src', '/like.png'

src: [Rails 3.1 CoffeeScript/JQuery - How to change the source of an image in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555528/rails-3-1-coffeescript-jquery-how-to-change-the-source-of-an-image-in-a-div)

Comment: That part makes sense but I'm confused on how to make the image auto change on click without the user having to refresh the page. Right now, if the user clicks on the "Like" text, the like is counted and the text automatically becomes "Dislike" and vice versa.